# Data storage in flash drives

Tags: data, energy-storage

In a pen drive, I have read that data is stored by trapping the electrical signals sent from the computer in silicon dioxide chambers. But what I dont understand is that how does the electrical signal stay stored in the chamber for long periods of time without changing its voltage.Wont it eventually fade out without a power source and for how long can a pen drive typically hold the signals?

Comment: Flash drives use NAND Flash Memory. Have you looked at [the Wikipedia article that describes this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory)?

Comment: Yes, but it hasnt been mentioned about how the flash drive holds a signal for long periods without changing its value and besides, I need a simple explanation in order to understand the logic behind it

Comment: It's not 'voltage' that is stored in each cell - it's charge (basically a bunch of electrons) which is stored. It works like a simple capacitor - you need some energy (voltage) to charge it, but then it holds its charge for a very long time, because electrons can't move through an insulator without some additional voltage applied (which you do when you need to erase the information - and even when they don't move through an oxide layer, they just go back the way they came).